# jQuery: indexing arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a Rails app in to which I want to submit a series of comma-separated IDs in a text field. For instance, let's say I was adding three elements to an order w/ respective IDs 12, 2, and 4, I would like the field to read:

```
12,2,4
```

Which is easy enough. The problem shows up when I've changed my mind and I want to replace an element in a certain position, i.e., the start, to an element with an ID of let's say 3. How would I manage to submit `3,2,4` and not `2,4,3`? I'm pretty stuck. And if there's a method of automatically putting commas only between the IDs (not at the start or the end) in the field that'd be hugely useful.

Cheers!

**Edit:** I've written this in an attempt to solve this problem. It feels close but no cigar yet. The `src` mentioned below contains one of the three IDs mentioned above, and there is a changing number of the `#elementX`s to which this function will be attached.

```
$('#element1').change(function() {
  var src = $(this).val();
  var array = $('#order').val().split(",");
  array.splice(0, 1, src).join(",");
  $('#order').val(array);
}
```

Comment: Mileorsohigh, you will find it much easier to work with separate fields rather than one field containing a composite value. jQuery then makes changes/deletions/additions trivial. Of course, the server-side code needs to be compatible with this approach.

Comment: I want an array in one field because the number of elements can vary significantly.

Comment: Yes, of course. You would generate them dynamically, which is also trivial.

Comment: Oh, generate the fields dynamically then compile them to submit them?

Comment: I'm not sure about "compile" but I'm not a rails person. I was assuming client-side generation. Rails requires a different mindset.

Comment: Doh! I think I understand what you mean by "compile" now. It's easier to do this with field names of the format `name="code[]"`. The form can then be submitted without pre-processing, and the server-side code should be able to pick up the codes as an array of values. This feature is built into most server-side scripting languages - I'm sure Rails must be capable of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three steps.  You're starting with a string containing comma-separated integers.

1. [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on the commas into an array of ids.
2. [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the new id into the array replacing the old id. You want to pass 3 parameters to splice:

   - The index of the element you want to start removing from (if you want to remove the first element, its index would be 0).
   - How many elements you want to remove (here you just want to remove the first element, so 1).
   - The new element to add in (in your case, it's `src`).
3. [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the string back together on a comma.

Comment: I've written this. It's not working but it feels close.
`var array = $('#orders').val().split(",");`
`array.splice(1, 0, src).join(",");`
`$('#orders').val(array);`

Comment: @mileorsohigh, I'm not sure you're using `splice` correctly.  What is the value of `src` in your code?  Edit your question to contain the code, it'll be easier to reason about there than in comments.

Comment: Perfect! Thank-you. I'll update my code for a working version should it help someone else.